# Filtering newsfeed to be specific type using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-fql, readonly

I'm trying to submit a query for a specific type of status sent to a user's newsfeed, where type=video. I basically want all videos posted for a user, including those not hosted by FB (otherwise I would submit a videos query). I would like it if I could get FB to not return anything except videos, but I certainly don't see a solution for that. I don't see that the returned query even has a field that will contain this information, so that I can filter the returned info. Is there any field in the stream table that will tell me the type of post?

Here's my initial starting point for the query:

```sql
SELECT post_id, from, name, source, link, picture, updated_time, comments 
FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() 
AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0
```

Comment: I think you can use the Attachment field ("An array of information about the attachment to the post.") in the Stream table. It has a  Type - ["type"]=> string(5) "video".

Answer (score 1):

You can set a type for the stream (see [ref](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/)), but video (*type = 128*) will return only uploaded videos.

```sql
SELECT post_id, source_id, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment, permalink, type 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id IN (SELECT target_id
    FROM connection
    WHERE source_id = me() AND is_following = 1) 
AND is_hidden = 0 
AND type = 128
```

This is in contradiction to using the graph api (e.g. js sdk: `FB.api('/me/home', function(response) {} )`), where `type: 'video'` is given to attached video links (e.g. YouTube)

However, the *attachment.media[0]* field, identifies video links as being `type: video`; but that is an array (and I didn't know how to query in them) so I checked if the link contained a reference to youtube (youtube links can be long-form or shortened, *youtu.be*)

```sql
SELECT post_id, source_id, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment, permalink, type 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id IN (SELECT target_id
    FROM connection
    WHERE source_id=me() AND is_following=1) 
AND is_hidden = 0 
AND type = 80 
AND strpos(attachment.href, "youtu") >= 0
```

Comment: Great answer! where i can find more available functions i can use in the query (like strpos...)?

Comment: Well, here's the reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/. It's kinda limited, maybe you can use `IN` instead of `strpos()`.